# Вывод даты без времени

Tags: datetime, php, mysql

Мне надо вывести дату без времени из базы данных. В бд она записана так: **04.01.2015 16:25**, а мне надо, чтобы в запросе выводил только **04.01.2015**

Вот такой скрипт есть, но он не работает.

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1), DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') FROM table WHERE date = '04.01.2015'");
```

mysql:

```
table
date    varchar(50)     00.00.0000 00:00:00
```

Comment: Можно в переменную заносить полную строку, но после отрезать её с помощью некоторой функции.

Comment: ну так смените varchar на datetime

Comment: @Etki, +1. и немедленно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms179859.aspx)